# How to avoid making defensive copies of ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, immutability, nio

I've got a class that takes a ByteBuffer as a constructor argument. Is there a way to avoid making defensive copies in order to ensure that the buffer doesn't get modified past that point?

ByteBuffer.isReadOnly() doesn't guarantee that the original owner won't modifying the buffer. To make matters worse, there doesn't seem to be a way to subclass ByteBuffer. Any ideas?

Comment: +1. Nice good-practices question.

Comment: Sounds like what the recipient needs is a copy-on-write byte buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could do for now:

```
/**
 * Helper functions for java.nio.Buffer.
 * <p/>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class Buffers
{
    /**
     * Returns a ByteBuffer that is identical but distinct from the original buffer.
     * <p/>
     * @param original the buffer to copy
     * @return an independent copy of original
     * @throws NullPointerException if original is null
     */
    public static ByteBuffer clone(ByteBuffer original)
    {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(original, "original may not be null");

        ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(original.capacity());
        ByteBuffer source = original.duplicate();
        source.rewind();
        result.put(source);

        try
        {
            source.reset();
            result.position(source.position());
            result.mark();
        }
        catch (InvalidMarkException unused)
        {
            // Mark is unset, ignore.
        }
        result.position(original.position());
        result.limit(original.limit());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array representation of a buffer. The returned buffer may, or may not, be tied to
     * the underlying buffer's contents (so it should not be modified).
     * <p/>
     * @param buffer the buffer
     * @return the remaining bytes
     */
    public static byte[] toArray(ByteBuffer buffer)
    {
        if (buffer.hasArray() && !buffer.isReadOnly() && buffer.position() == 0
            && buffer.remaining() == buffer.limit())
        {
            return buffer.array();
        }
        ByteBuffer copy = buffer.duplicate();
        byte[] result = new byte[copy.remaining()];
        copy.get(result);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Prevent construction.
     */
    private Buffers()
    {
    }
}
```

I've also filed a feature request with Oracle: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7130631

Answer (score 4):

The only real way is, as you say, `buf.asReadOnlyBuffer()`, then pass this into the constructor. There's no other option apart from this, although you could do a copy of the contents into a new `ByteBuffer`, then pass that.

Comment: Even if the constructor receives a read-only buffer, it has no way of guaranteeing that the buffer will not be modified by the original owner (who retained write-access). So you're still forced to make a defensive copy.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't avoid a copy, but perhaps:

1. Use a pre-filled pool of pre-allocated ByteBuffers
2. Allow the
   constructor of Author's class to allow a 'copy' of incoming
   ByteBuffer, but have class use a ByteBuffer from the pool to move
   Alloc/Dealloc costs to app startup/shutdown.  Only pay a memcopy cost this way.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer the question, but, for some usages (e.g. if you are mainly trying to enforce "design by contract") it may be good enough and more efficient.  For other usages it will not work and may be far less efficient.

During your constructor, save away the hashCode of the ByteBuffer

final int originalBBHashCode = byteBuffer.hashCode();

Then, at the few critical places in your code where you want to verify that the ByteBuffer hasn't changed, verify that the byteBuffer.hashCode() == originalBBHashCode.  If not, throw an exception.  Frankly, I'd be tempted to throw a ConcurrentModificationException, since that is the behavior you are mimicking, but YMMV.